# Не работает [checked] = "item.isCompleted"> в angular

Tags: angular

Всем доброго дня. Я столкнулся с проблемой, что у меня не работает [checked] = "item.isCompleted">

Вот моя разметка:

```
<li *ngFor="let todo of todoList">

    <div *ngFor="let item of todo.todos">
      <div>{{item | json}}</div>
          <input type="checkbox"
          name="isCompleted"
          [checked] = "item.isCompleted">
          
   <span *ngIf="item.isCompleted">{{ item.text }}</span>
   <span *ngIf="!item.isCompleted"><del>{{ item.text }}</del></span>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?

Comment: Проверил конструкцию `[checked] = "true/false"``, работает в зависимости от условия. В чем конкретно проявляется нерабочее поведение.  Опиши, что делаешь, что хочешь получить, что получил. Больше подробностей - быстрее и проще ответ. Сейчас невозможно дать ответ.

Comment: @Sergey Glazirin, спасибо, что ответил - я решение нашел по этой ссылке: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2                               
[checked] = "item.isCompleted" заменил на           
 [(ngModel)] = "item.isCompleted">